# Cast VARCHAR to Datetime

Tags: datetime, casting, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to convert a string datetime, to a timestamp. try_to_timestamp isn't converting dates in the yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss AM/PM format. I've only been able to solve this by striping out the time and casting it as a type time and concatenating it back with the date. Anyone know of a Snowflake function to handle this?

select try_to_timestamp('2019-11-18 4:01:29 PM +0000')

Comment: This is more or less a duplicate of question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59030297/how-can-i-parse-an-iso-8601-timestamp-with-snowflake-sql

Answer (score 2):

your timestamp doesn't quite fit the ISO or RTC formats so it's not automatically detecting it. You can manually put in your format though. Should look something like this:

```
select to_timestamp('2019-11-18 4:01:29 PM +0000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH12:MI:SS AM TZHTZM')
```

For information on the various formats SnowFlake uses: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/date-time-input-output.html

**EDIT:**
You may or may not want to cast it as a timestamp_tz (timestamp with timezone) to maintain timezone information

```
select to_timestamp_tz('2019-11-18 4:01:29 PM +0200', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH12:MI:SS AM TZHTZM');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since try_to_timestamp does not support a format, you can set it before calling the 
try_to_timestamp function.  The example below is setting it at the session level.

```
 alter session set TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH12:MI:SS AM TZHTZM'; 

 select  try_to_timestamp('2019-11-18 4:01:29 PM +0000');
```

Comment: good point. I missed the "try". Some combination of our two answers should work though.